# show selected columns of table in QlikView

Tags: dashboard, qlikview

I am creating a Dashboard in QlikView, allowing the user to extract data based on the filters and selected columns. Requirments are below.

1. “Data Extract” table MUST be **empty** (even no column names are showed)at first!
2. Clicking the blue button shows the list of data available.
3. A table will then show those selected columns.

Does someone know how to do these?

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a conditional expression on each of your dimension and measures.
A simple example would be to have an ID for each measure, here the measure "NetSales" can be referenced by MeasureID "a".

```
Measure | MeasureID
NetSales | a
```

In the conditional expression for NetSales you can have:

```
=if(IsNull(GetFieldSelections(Measure)),0,SubStringCount(Concat(MeasureID, '|'), 'a'))
```

This will check the possible MeasureIDs and return 1 if NetSales is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "floating" tables with the dimensions & expressions you need to use in the table object:

Here is an example I made : https://ufile.io/j20am (just reload the file If you use personal edition)